# ElasticSearch: Fulltext search in array ignoring documents where the sought text is a part of array's element

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ES ver. 5.4.3

Documents have such mapping:

```
mappings {
    folders {
        properties {
            id {
                type "long"
            }
            records {
                properties {
                    name {
                        type "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have two documents ("folders"):

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        records: [
            {
                name: "foo"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        records: [
            {
                name: "foo bar"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected result: return only "foo" folder if "foo" is being requested (not both) and only "foo bar" - if "foo bar" is being requested.

I try to use "match_phrase" query and it works fine in case of "foo bar", but if I use it with "foo" ES returns both "folders".

my problem query is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "records.name": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know if there are some options to return only id=1 if "foo" is requested?

Comment: `{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"terms": {"records.name": ["foo bar"]}}]}}}` doesn't return results for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field `records.name` will be of type keyword, you can then make use of [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-term-query.html)

If you have `records.name` as only of type text in the index mapping, it would be better to add its `keyword` field as multi-fields, so that you can make use of `records.name` for text matches and `records.name.keyword` for exact matches.

Adding a working example with index mapping, data and search query. (Tried the below search query in Elasticsearch version 5.6)

**Index Mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "records": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "foo"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "foo bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search Query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "records.name.keyword": "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "records": [
                        {
                            "name": "foo"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```